# How to shift labels in Python using Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython

I'm trying to shift labels of a LabeledPoint so that they start from 0. Right now parsedDataInit.take(1) looks like this before the code at the bottom:

```
[LabeledPoint(2001.0,[0.884123733793,0.610454259079,0.600498416968,0.474669212493,0.247232680947,0.357306088914,0.344136412234,0.339641227335,0.600858840135,0.425704689024,0.60491501652,0.419193351817])]
```

The labels are the years, for example, 2001.0 is the max year and 1922.0 is the min year. The difference is 89.0 and what I am trying to do is shift the labels so that they start from 0, making the new minYear 0 and the new maxYear 89 while still maintaining the same features. I'm new to apache spark and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```
parsedData = parsedDataInit.map(lambda lp: lp.label) # This is where I'm having trouble
print type(parsedData.take(1)[0])
print '\n{0}'.format(parsedData.take(1))
```

Comment: "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._"  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is from the Edx Scalable machine learning MOOC Lab homework!! There is piazza for asking questions about your homework.

Comment: @eliasah, thanks for your comment. I just today stuck on another apache spark course. And after reading your comment  I understood now, that this course (I can't named it here) just copy paste from edx)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just subtract the minimum from each year.

```
def normalize(data):
  labels = data.map(lambda lp: lp.label)
  minLabel = labels.min()
  return data.map(
    lambda lp: LabeledPoint(lp.label - minLabel, lp.features))
```

Answer (score 1):

based on @Daniel response a one line solution to the problem (without creating any new functions):

`parsedData = parsedDataInit.map(lambda lp:LabeledPoint(lp.label - minYear, lp.features))`